# Cannot remote connect to Windows 2019 core

Tags: windows-server-core, windows-server-2019

I tried to copy files to Windows server 2019 core referring to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt708806(v=vs.85).aspx. But after i ran the commands:
*$ip = "192.168.0.100"  # replace with your Nano Server's IP address
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ip -Credential ~\Administrator*

I got below errors:
[image]

I have already add the two servers into the trustedhosts in each other's local files(Set-Item WSMAN:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts srvname -force), and also disable the firewall on the remote server.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Does it work if you use the name instead of the IP address?

Comment: Awesome!  It works now! You are a hero @GregAskew!

Answer (score 2):

This link will be helpful in resolving Enter-PSSession (http://jeffgraves.me/2013/10/14/powershell-remoting/) WinRM denies.

For our specific case we did the following:

On the Local machine
winrm quickconfig (although this was already configured)

winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="myservername.domain"}'

On the Remote machine

enable-psremoting -force

Set-PSSessionConfiguration -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI -Name Microsoft.PowerShell -Force

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062033/cannot-create-remote-powershell-session-after-enable-psremoting

Comment: Thank you Stuka, I have tried the steps above but still encounter the same error..